# how to jump a list member in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, twitter, tweepy

so I'm trying to send i message to a group of people . I want to know how can I jump to 'test2' (next list member )  if 'test1' (current list member ) got an error .

```
profile_id = ['test1','test2']
for ids in profile_id:
    api.send_direct_message(ids,text)
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'got an error'? How would you recognize an error?

Comment: The `for` loop does that, you have to use the iteration variable (`ids`) inside of it though.

Comment: Use `try/except` to catch the error so you can continue with the next list member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Menashe already said, you can use TRY, EXCEPT and PASS.
like this:

```
profile_id = ['test1','test2']
for ids in profile_id:
    try:
       api.send_direct_message(ids,text)
    except:
       pass
```

Answer (score 2):

`for` iterates trough iprofile_id. So, the variable `ids` will first be the element `'test 1'`, do whatever is inside the for loop (i.e., send message to the person that is called `'test 1'`. Then `ids` becomes `'test2'`, and a message is sent to `'test2'`. But you try sending a message to the list of people, not the person picked (`ids`). I assume that the function `send_direct_message` does not allow lists, so therefore you need to have your third line be `api.send_direct_message(ids, text)`.

Comment: In addition: To check if you get an error you can, as Menashe Aharonian pointed out, use Try/Except ( https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement )

Answer (score 2):

Why not use TRY and then EXCEPT for the relevant class?

You can then use PASS to do nothing and continue to the next.

Comment: Next time, please try to put the whole snippet with the answer, not just say to use try except. As a beginner who asked the question, he / she might not know what you meant by **use try except**.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `try/except` for that, but only in a case if you `raise` an exception in `send_direct_message`

```
profile_ids = ['test1','test2']
for index, profile_id in enumerate(profile_ids):
    try:
        api.send_direct_message(profile_id,text)
    # assume that using just Exception is not a good tone, try to use specific exception you raise in the method here instead of just Exception
    except Exception as exc:
        if (index+1) >= len(profile_ids):
            break
        api.send_direct_message(profile_ids[index+1], text)
        # but in such a case think of list index out of range error, that will be thrown when list will go to an end
```